# Spring JPA inserts null foreign key on save (OneToOne Bidirectional Mapping)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having issues with a **OneToOne** Bidirectional Mapping using Spring JPA (Kotlin). I have an `Event` and an `EventAddress` associated to it. Each `Event` can have one `EventAddress` and similarly each `EventAddress` can have one `Event` associated with it. I am using the `CrudRepository` interface to insert an `Event`, in which I first assign an `EventAddress` to the `Event` and then save it using the `EventsRepository` save() method.

Here are stripped down versions of my models:

```
@Entity(name = "events")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
class Event(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var eventId: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "event",
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    var address: EventAddress? = null,

    @CreatedDate
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

    @LastModifiedDate
    var updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

```
@Entity(name = "event_address")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
class EventAddress(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var eventAddressId: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    var event: Event? = null,

    @CreatedDate
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

    @LastModifiedDate
    var updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

When I insert an `Event` (which has an address on it), a row is inserted into the `Event` table, and a row is inserted into the `EventAddress` table. The problem is in the `EventAddress` table, the foreign key (event_id) is always NULL.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.. any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the EventAddress have the event reference set? The foreign key within event_address is controlled by the EventAddress.event property, so if it isn't set, it will be left null - this is a common question/problem with bidirectional relationships; always set both sides as you are responsible for keeping the model in synch with what is in the database. JPA will look at the owning side of the relationship to set foreign keys when they are not in synch.

Comment: That was it! I needed to set both the `event` on the `EventAddress` and the `address` on the `Event`. Thank you